# Scrape data from Chrome extension to Google Sheets

Tags: google-chrome, google-sheets, google-chrome-extension

I have this  Chrome Extension (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/history-trends/nangghhladpnhlllolmdbdgeggionole) called History Trends which amongst other things displays the number of times I visit a website. I would like to get this number in to my google sheet so that I can track it day by day. Is this possible or does it not work with chrome extensions? I have tried the following formula: =IMPORTXML(A127;"//*[@id=""per_day_stats""]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]") where A127 is: chrome-extension://nangghhladpnhlllolmdbdgeggionole/trends.html, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is my look on your problem.

### Why it's not working

You have to understand the protocol you are using (the thing before the `://` in the URL) is not `http` nor `https` and yes `chrome-extension`.

It's an extension from chrome only. So to help understand, if we (you there and me here) are trying to fetch the same URL (chrome-extension://nangghhladpnhlllolmdbdgeggionole/trends.html), which data will it give back? Mine or yours?

A chrome extension lives in your browser with your data, and in my browser with my data.

Also, you need to understand that when a google sheet fetches for any data, it is not using your connection, but yes it is calling the data from the Google servers itself. An example of that is that if you google "what is my ip": (or follow the following link https://ifconfig.me/ip) you will have a number, and if you try to do the same in your google sheets' sheet:

`=IMPORTDATA("https://ifconfig.me/ip")`

you will have a different number. Meaning that the IP where the data is being fetched is not the same that your network provider is assigning to you.

This is all to say that where you are trying to scrape with google sheets, you are doing a request from a server in google to another server where the webpage is hosted. Below is the geolocalization of the IP that was the result of the google sheets formula, it is possible to see it was fetched from google:

[image]

Even though you access the google sheets from your browser, it does not live in your browser, but in the google cloud, and it doesn't have access to your browser's information.

Now, even though it doesn't give you a solution, it may help you understand what is happening when you ask google sheets to import data from any source.

I googled for an already long time and I couldn't find a solution for this problem of yours. So I can't help you for now, and if I find any solution I'll update this answer, but for the moment this is all I can help.

(To note that that huge string (*nangghhladpnhlllolmdbdgeggionole*) is the identity of the chrome extension itself and not a random string assigned differently per browser session)